# Substituting by pattern in regex

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I have a file filled with rows which looks like:

> some_var = "value"

and I would like to change it (using regex), to:

> "some_var" : "value"

the regex for finding the "some_var" group is simple as: `(?P<some_var_group>[a-z_]+)\s+=\s\".*\"`
But, how do I add `"` before, and after the `some_var_group`.

This question is not only about this specific problem, I would really like to know how to replace by pattern.

Thanks Ahead!

Comment: So, is it in python or js?

Comment: umm actually it doesn't really matter to me because I can work with both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

python:

```
import re

text = 'some_var = "value"'

regex = r'([a-z_]+)\s*=\s*"(.+?)"'
print re.sub(regex, r'"\1":"\2"', text)
```

js:

```
text = 'some_var = "value"'

regex = /([a-z_]+)\s*=\s*"(.+?)"/
console.log(text.replace(regex, '"$1":"$2"'))
```

Comment: Is there an option to write it down with group naming? just for code readability, (instead of \1 or $1, the name of the group)

Comment: @Hamus: in python yes, `\g<groupName>`, js doesn't support named groups